# SSRAS Auto Refresh and Auto Paging

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to get a report to work in "Kiosk" mode... to show on a big plasma screen and refresh every 30 seconds.

I know how to set the "AutoRefresh" property to 30 sec. but what I don't know is how can i get my report to page to the next page on every refresh .. and then when he gets to the last page start form the beginning.

Is there a way to achieve this in ssrs2008r2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a Table-Valued Function or Stored Procedure for a report Dataset. Within this I would increment the "page count" every time it executes e.g. by updating a table.

Then (again within that source TVF or SP) I would use the current "page count" to filter the rows returned, and/or return the current "page count" as a column for SSRS Expressions to Hide report objects on the other pages.

Comment: I cannot add any object to the DB .. i can just create reports

Comment: SSRS by definition is hosted on a SQL Server which already has had at least 2 SSRS-specific databases added. I would request a new empty database which you can use as you please to suit SSRS requirements. If this is a different SQL Server from your source database, and you need to filter rows, then you may need to use the "page count" results from that new database as an SSRS Filter or in a Row Visibility expression.

Comment: Or ... depending on what your exact paging requirements are, you may be able to come up with an Expression to turn the current time into a page number, e.g. "it's 09:02:30 AM, so I should be on page 5"

Comment: Finally what i did is I have created a query that accepts @pageNum as a parameter from the report... This parameter gets his default value by using the following formula `CurrentTimeInSeconds/RepfreshTimeInSeconds % TotalPages` this will allow cycling thorught pages according to passing time .. it has some issues because it will not necessarily start from the first page  and in case the value of `CurrentTimeInSeconds/RepfreshTimeInSeconds` is smaller that the total pages, but it works for most cases as there are 86400 seconds in 24 hours so ..